# Unable to add WebP to ImageMagick

Tags: ubuntu, imagemagick, webp

I'm trying to add WebP support to ImageMagick but it does not.

First I've installed **libwebp** 1.0.2 (https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/compiling#building), so `cwebp -q 80 image.png -o image.webp` works correctly and the library's path exists in `/lib/ld-linux.so.2`

After I'm trying to configure **ImageMagick** with WebP support adding `--with-webp=yes` option. In some trials I used `LDFLAGS=/usr/local/lib` also but anyway log shows
`WEBP              --with-webp=yes             no`

for me it looks like IM conf not able to see webp libraries. If so how can I point IM to use existing WebP libraries or, please, guide me the right way to add WebP support to IM.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I do not know if this will help, but see https://imagemagick.org/script/formats.php and look at the comments for webp

Answer (score 1):

Have you got `pkgconfig` installed? If not, consider installing it and see if it finds the WEBP stuff with:

```
pkg-config --exists libwebp
```

If not, you can try adding to the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`. So, if you find where you installed WEBP and look under that directory, you should find a file ending in `.pc` which holds the `pkgconfig` settings. Then add the containing directory to your `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` variable. So, if the `web.pc` is in `/usr/freddy/frog/webp.pc`, you need to do:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/freddy/frog
```

Then try again to see if the command below works:

```
pkg-config --exists libwebp
```

---

Else, you can try setting the environment variables:

```
WEBP_CFLAGS
WEBP_LIBS
```

which will override the `pkgconfig` settings.

Comment: Also see this thread answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70188280/2039041