# Compiling ImageMagick: Cannot Find 'libwebp', compiled From Source on Amazon Linux 2

Tags: php, linux, amazon-ec2, imagick, webp

I am trying to recompile ImageMagick to enable webp support for PHP.

The issue appears to be that when compiling Imagick using `./configure --with-webp=yes` it cannot find a libwebp library with a higher version than `0.4.1`. Amazon Linux 2's repos only go up to version `0.3.1`. This means compiling libwebp from source, which works but Imagick does not seem to recognize it.

So my question is, how do I ensure ImageMagick can find and use the libwebp library?

### Steps

To compile from the source I have done the following:

```
cd /var
sudo wget https://storage.googleapis.com/downloads.webmproject.org/releases/webp/libwebp-1.1.0.tar.gz
sudo tar xvzf libwebp-1.1.0.tar.gz
cd libwebp-1.1.0
sudo ./configure
sudo make && sudo make install
```

`/sbin/ldconfig -p | grep webp` shows the following output which shows libwebp library exists in the `/usr/local/lib` dir as expected and registered in the ld config.

```
   libwebpdemux.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libwebpdemux.so.2
   libwebpdemux.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libwebpdemux.so
   libwebp.so.7 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libwebp.so.7
   libwebp.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libwebp.so
```

I then try to compile Imagick from source by doing the following:

```
cd /var
sudo wget https://imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick.tar.gz
sudo tar xvzf ImageMagick.tar.gz
cd ImageMagick-7.1.0-7
sudo ./configure --with-webp=yes
sudo make && sudo make install
sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib
```

However, when running `./configure --with-webp=yes`, I get the following output

```
...

-------------------------------------------------------------
checking for libwebp >= 0.4.1... no
checking for libwebpmux >= 0.5.0 libwebpdemux >= 0.5.0... no

checking if WMF package is complete... no
-------------------------------------------------------------

...

configure:
==============================================================================
ImageMagick 7.1.0-7 is configured as follows. Please verify that this
configuration matches your expectations.

Host system type: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Build system type: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

                  Option                        Value
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Shared libraries  --enable-shared=yes           yes
Static libraries  --enable-static=yes           yes
Build utilities   --with-utilities=yes          yes
Module support    --with-modules=no             no
GNU ld            --with-gnu-ld=yes             yes
Quantum depth     --with-quantum-depth=16       16
High Dynamic Range Imagery
                  --enable-hdri=yes             yes

Install documentation:                          yes

Memory allocation library:
  JEMalloc          --with-jemalloc=no          no
  TCMalloc          --with-tcmalloc=no          no
  UMem              --with-umem=no              no

Delegate library configuration:
  BZLIB             --with-bzlib=yes            no
  Autotrace         --with-autotrace=no         no
  DJVU              --with-djvu=yes             no
  DPS               --with-dps=yes              no
  FFTW              --with-fftw=no              no
  FLIF              --with-flif=yes             no
  FlashPIX          --with-fpx=yes              no
  FontConfig        --with-fontconfig=yes       no
  FreeType          --with-freetype=yes         no
  Ghostscript lib   --with-gslib=no             no
  Graphviz          --with-gvc=yes              no
  HEIC              --with-heic=yes             no
  JBIG              --with-jbig=yes             no
  JPEG v1           --with-jpeg=yes             yes
  JPEG XL           --with-jxl=no               no
  LCMS              --with-lcms=yes             no
  LQR               --with-lqr=yes              no
  LTDL              --with-ltdl=no              no
  LZMA              --with-lzma=yes             no
  Magick++          --with-magick-plus-plus=yes no (failed tests)
  OpenEXR           --with-openexr=yes          no
  OpenJP2           --with-openjp2=yes          no
  PANGO             --with-pango=yes            no
  PERL              --with-perl=no              no
  PNG               --with-png=yes              yes
  RAQM              --with-raqm=yes             no
  RAW               --with-raw=yes              no
  RSVG              --with-rsvg=no              no
  TIFF              --with-tiff=yes             yes
  WEBP              --with-webp=yes             no
  WMF               --with-wmf=no               no
  X11               --with-x=                   no
  XML               --with-xml=yes              no
  ZIP               --with-zip=yes              no
  ZLIB              --with-zlib=yes             yes
  ZSTD              --with-zstd=yes             no

Delegate program configuration:
  GhostPCL          None                        pcl6 (unknown)
  GhostXPS          None                        gxps (unknown)
  Ghostscript       None                        gs (9.25)

Font configuration:
  Apple fonts       --with-apple-font-dir=default
  Dejavu fonts      --with-dejavu-font-dir=default      none
  Ghostscript fonts --with-gs-font-dir=default          /share/ghostscript/fonts/
  URW-base35 fonts  --with-urw-base35-font-dir=default  none
  Windows fonts     --with-windows-font-dir=default     none

X11 configuration:
  X_CFLAGS        = 
  X_PRE_LIBS      = 
  X_LIBS          = 
  X_EXTRA_LIBS    = 

Options used to compile and link:
  PREFIX          = /usr/local
  EXEC-PREFIX     = /usr/local
  VERSION         = 7.1.0-7
  CC              = gcc
  CFLAGS          = -I/usr/include/libpng15     -fopenmp -Wall -g -O2 -mtune=haswell -fexceptions -pthread -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16
  CPPFLAGS        =  -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16
  PCFLAGS         = 
  DEFS            = -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
  LDFLAGS         = 
  LIBS            =    -ltiff   -ljpeg    -lpng15                           -lz       -lm    -lpthread 
  CXX             = g++
  CXXFLAGS        =  -pthread
  FEATURES        = DPC HDRI Cipher OpenMP
  DELEGATES       = jng jpeg png ps tiff zlib
==============================================================================
```

#### Related posts:

https://github.com/rosell-dk/webp-convert/wiki/Installing-Imagick-extension-with-WebP-support
https://legacy.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=35892
[Add WebP to ImageMagick supported formats for PHP 7.3 on a WHM dedicated server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57223153/add-webp-to-imagemagick-supported-formats-for-php-7-3-on-a-whm-dedicated-server/61401596#61401596)
https://library.roguewave.com/display/SUPPORT/How+to+compile+Imagick+PHP+extension+with+WebP+support

Comment: »»ensure ImageMagick can find and use the libwebp library«« : You configured libwebp-1.1.0 to /usr/local/, which is last in the search path : The old version is found . ..... libwebp, suggest : `./configure --prefix=/usr`

Comment: How did you resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

For the libraries to be found, you've got to make sure pkgconfig sees the .pc files `/usr/lib/pkgconfig`

Add `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to your `.bash_profile`, source it and check using `pkg-config --list-all | grep webp`.
If the libraries are found, try `./configure --with-webp=yes` again.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar issue when trying to configure ImageMagick-7.1.0 on Amazon Linux 2022.

When I ran `pkg-config --list-all | grep webp` per @Juukie14's suggestion, I received:

```
/usr/bin/pkg-config: line 8: /usr/bin/aarch64-redhat-linux-gnu-pkg-config: No such file or directory
```

For whatever reason, pkg-config installed from the AL2022 package repository is looking for `arch64-redhat-linux-gnu-pkg-config` when it should be `/usr/bin/aarch64-amazon-linux-gnu-pkg-config`.

As a workaround, I created a symlink:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/aarch64-amazon-linux-gnu-pkg-config /usr/bin/aarch64-redhat-linux-gnu-pkg-config
```

After this, I ran `./configure --with-webp=yes` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by adding `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH like that

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

Then configuring and installing ImageMagick completed successfully with webp support.